# Magento discount and Promo Discount limitation

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento Version 1.9.1.1, Apply discount which is in higher side, normal product discount or promo code discount.

if the catalog discount is 10% and Promo discount is 20% then 20% promo discount should apply instead of 10%.

if the normal discount is 30% and promo discount is 10% then normal discount 30% should apply.

How to handle it in magento. Stop further rule will apply either catalog or Promo, but my requirement is give the discount which is higher.

suggestions please.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I would be very glad to know.